# Core dumped error while trying to store double values in an array

Tags: c, error-handling

For some reason, when I enter more values than the size of the array, the program returns an array with a weird value, then sorts it, and then the program returns an error saying "core dumped". My function shouldn't be out of bounds...

`    //Function to store values from command line into array

```
void store_array(int argc, char *argv[], double arr[], int max_size){
    if (argc<2){
      printf("If you wish to store values in the array, enter them after the program       command!\n");
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc && i <= max_size; i++) {
        arr[i-1] = atof(argv[i]);
    }
    if (argc - 1 > max_size){
      printf("Sorry, but this function can only store %d values. The rest of the values weren't used.", max_size);
    }
}




// Function to sort the array
void sort_arrays(double array[], int array_size){

  int step, i;
  double tmp;

  for (step = 0; step < array_size-1; step++){
    for (i=0; i < array_size - step - 1; i++){
      if (array[i] > array[i+1]){
        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = tmp;
      }  
    }    
  }
  return;
}

// Function to print the array

void print_double_array(double a2[], int num_entries){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
      printf("%.2f\n", a2[i]);
  }
}`
```

I used an array with a max_size of 10, below you will find my function to store the values into an array, to print the array, and the one to sort it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make your code a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please edit to also include how you call your functions. Please also show the input you provide, together with output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you might be passing incorrect `array_size`/`num_entries` value to `sort_arrays()` or `print_double_array()`, because you are not returning the number of items in array from `store_array()`. Probably you need to take `min(argc-1, max_size)` as an array size, but it's too easy to forget about it and pass `argc-1`.

I would change `store_array()` to return the actual array size to avoid such situations.

Comment: I am not quite sure I fully get it. Could you expand?

Comment: Could you please share the fragment of code where you are calling `sort_arrays()` and `print_double_array()`? The question is what are you passing as the second parameter.

Comment: Of course, here is the at2.c fragment of code where I call the functions:

`#define DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE (10)
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
      int numEntries = argc - 1; // Number of entries written by user on commmand line.

    double double_array[DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE]; // Array with command line input

    // Storing the values entered on the command line into the array. 
  
  store_array(argc, argv, double_array, DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE);

    // PRINT SORTED ARRAY HERE
      printf("Sorted Array:\n");
      print_double_array(double_array, numEntries);`

Comment: You call `print_double_array(double_array, numEntries)`. `numEntries = argc-1`. So if you pass more than 10 arguments to your program it will go out of bounds. You know the actual size of entered data in `store_array` function. So if you return it from there and use when calling `print_double_array()`it should fix the problem.